# MouseMove event for div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of svg element in a div

```
<div id="parent">
    <rect width='600' height='600'> </rect>
    <g>
        <path d="M  285 0 L 285 0 L 318.34499999999997 57.5055 L 251.655 57.5055 z"/>
    </g>
</div>
```

and bind a mousemove event to div element in document.ready as

```
 $("#parent").mousemove(function(event) {
     var child=$(evt.target)[0].nodeName;
 });
```

Even though moving on the path element in div, I am getting `$(evt.target)[0].nodeName` as "rect" in firefox, but in IE and chrome `$(evt.target)[0].nodeName` returns "path" as I want...

So I tried the following things:

1. binded the mousemove event for path element alone, but that too is not triggering in firefox.
2. `$(evt.target).closest("#path")` not working in firefox.

The problem is mousemove  on path element returns target as "rect" in firefox. Please tell me any alternative solution for this. I need to capture the mousemove event on path element in div.

Comment: `.closest('#path')` is going to search for an element with an `id` of `path`. Did you mean to use `.closest('path')`, which will search for an element with a *tag name* of `path`, which would be your `<path>` element?

Comment: Hi, its just for reference, using id i used to find the closest element, 
<path id="pathElement" d="M  285 0 L 285 0 L 318.34499999999997 57.5055 L 251.655 57.5055 z"/>

.closest('pathElement')

Comment: You should edit that information into your question so that people don't have the same confusion or think that is the cause of your problem.